# Relationship in Laravel how to list data only when pivot is active

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relational-database

Using Laravel. I have the tables below in the MySQL database.

The infos table accepts 1 intermediary (table intermediaries) and 1 store (table stores).
How to get all the data from the infos table? But only where the pivot table (intermediary_store) is active = 1?

```
infos
- id
- name
- intermediary_id
- store_id

intermediaries
- id
- name

intermediary_store
- intermediary_id
- store_id
- active

stores
- id
- name
```

Models:

```
class Info extends Model
{
    public function intermediary()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Intermediary');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
    }
}


class Intermediary extends Model
{
    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Store')->withPivot('active');
    }
}

class Store extends Model
{
    public function intermediaries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Intermediary')->withPivot('active');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use `->wherePivot('active', 1)` when querying. Can you show the code you've tried and any errors you're getting? Also, might be helpful to post the Models and `belongsToMany()` relationships.

Comment: I put the models. Are they right?

Comment: Yup! Looks good to me :) So you should be able to do `Store::with(['intermediaries' => function($query){ $query->wherePivot('active', 1); }])->get();` to get all your `Store` models with active `Intermediary` models. And reverse it `Intermediary::with(['stores' => function($query){ $query->wherePivot('active', 1); }])->get();` to get all your `Intermediary` records with active `Store`s.

Comment: Yes. But to get all Infos data? Where (intermediary_id and store_id) should be active = 1

Comment: I don't think you need the `infos` table at all to be honest. Add `name` to `intermediary_store` table and add to `withPivot(['name', 'active'])`, and you have everything you need. Generally, you don't have a model for a pivot table.

Comment: Infos table is the important. It has more than 20 columns. The columns above I put for example. Should I add a relationship from the infos tables to intermediary_store?

Comment: Was in a meeting. I don't think that's the correct approach. You could just add `active` to your `infos` table, and have it serve as the pivot table, but again, you generally don't need a Model for it. `withPivot()` can handle 20+ columns, no problem, but you're gonna have a hard time with duplicated pivots like this.